# How do I create a running count of outcomes sequentially by date and unique to a specific person/ID?

Tags: r, excel, ms-access, machine-learning, feature-extraction

I have a list of unique customers who have made transactions over a year (Jan – Dec). They have bought products using 3 different methods (card, cash, check). My goal is to build a multi-classification model to predict the method pf payment.

To do this I am engineering some Recency and Frequency features into my training data, but am having trouble with the following frequency count because the only way I know how to do it is in Excel using the Countifs and SUMIFs functions, which are inhibitingly slow. If someone can help and/or suggest another solution, it would be very much appreciated:

So I have a data set with 3 columns (Customer ID, Purchase Date, and Payment Type) that is sorted by Purchase Date then Customer ID. How do I then get a prior frequency count of payment type by date that does not include the count of the current row transaction or any future transactions that are > the Purchase Date. So basically I want to do a running count of each payment option, based on a unique Customer ID, and a date range that is < purchase date of that training row. In my head I see it as “crawling” backwards through the transactions and counting. Simplified screenshot of data frame is below with the 3 prior count columns I am looking to generate programmatically.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZSE2.jpg)

Comment: Would a pivot table work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the answer as a list of CustomerID, PurchaseDate, PaymentMethod and prior counts

```
SELECT CustomerID, PurchaseDate, PaymentMethod,
           (
           select count(CustomerID) from History T
           where
                 T.CustomerID=History.CustomerID
                 and T.PaymentMethod=History.PaymentMethod
                 and T.PurchaseDate<History.PurchaseDate
           )
          AS PriorCount
FROM History;
```

You can save this query and use it as the source for a crosstab query to get the columnar format you want

Some notes:

- I assumed "History" as the source table name - you can change the query above to use the correct source
- To use this as a query, open a new query in design view.  Close the window that asks what tables the query is to be built on.  Open the SQL view of the query design - like design view, but it shows the SQL instead of the normal design interface.  Copy the above into the SQL view.
- You should now be able to switch to datasheet view and see the results
- When the query is working to your satisfaction, save it with any appropriate name
- Open a new query in design view
- When you get the list of tables to include, switch to the list of queries and include the query you just saved
- Change the query type to crosstab and update the query as needed to select rows, columns and values - look up "access crosstab queries" if you need more help.

Another tip to see what is happening here:

- You can take the subquery - the parts inside the () above - and make
  just that statement into it's own query, excluding the opening and closing ().  Then you can look at it's design view to see what it does
- Save it with an appropriate name and put it into the query above in place of the statement in () - then you can look at the design view.

Sometimes it's easier to visualize and learn from 2 queries strung together this way than to work with sub queries.

Comment: Don - First and foremost, thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately though, I'm a bit of a novice. Exactly how and where do I insert this query and then initialize a crosstab query off of it? Thanks.

Comment: Per your notes, do I do this within Excel and do I need to set up a SQL Server?

Comment: sorry - I thought you were working in Access, since you had that tag listed.    Everything here refers to an Access solution.

Comment: For an Excel solution, look at at the COUNTIFS formula with criteria for CustomerID, PurchaseDate and PaymentMethod.

Comment: Much thanks to everyone. The Access query that Don suggested works well.

Comment: Glad it worked - if your problem is fixed, can you please accept the answer for me?